# Polymer installation on windows

Tags: windows, polymer

Has anyone installed Polymer on windows? I am new to using GIT and it says you need Bower and Node and some other things to get it to work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We are working on a simple ZIP file for people to download and get started, but we haven't finished that yet.

Until we get that ZIP done, you will want to get started by installing [Bower](http://bower.io). Bower helps you manage component installations. You can worry about GIT later.

Install Bower:

1. Install [nodejs](http://nodejs.org/download/)
2. execute this command:

   `npm install -g bower`

Make a project, acquire some Polymer elements:

1. make a project folder
2. inside project folder, execute this command:

   `bower install Polymer/polymer-ui-elements`

That will produce a number of components in your project folder to help you get started. Please refer to http://polymer-project.org for more information.

Comment: I tried running that command and I got an error, it's saying that GIT is not installed or not in the Path. "bower ENOGIT git is not installed"

Comment: @SamCromer How did u solve it? I added by git.exe to the path, no luck.

Comment: In Windows 8 machine it worked for me by adding text in Path Environment Variable as `;%Program Files (x86)%\Git\bin;%Program Files (x86)%\Git\cmd`.

Answer (score 3):

**Step 1:-** install node.js

**Step 2:-** install Git 
     set the Git location Path (system's environmental variable)

```
       like:-- D:\Program Files\Git\cmd
```

**Step 3:-** install bower using *npm install -g bower command* check the location of npm global binaries by using command (**npm config get prefix**).

copy the Path and set the bower location Path (system's environmental variable)

```
        like--> C:\Users\USER_PROFILE\AppData\Roaming\npm
```

the whole Path will look like..(node to Polymer)

```
         D:\Program Files\nodejs\;D:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Users\USER_PROFILE\AppData\Roaming\npm
```

**Step 4:-** using command prompt go to project folder or create a project then type
          **bower install polymer**
          inside project 
        folder.